# How to populate list box in yii by using the following code

Tags: php, yii

```
$selected   = array( '5' => array('selected' => 'selected'),'6' => array('selected' => 'selected'),);
$htmlOptions = array('size' => '5', 'prompt'=>'Use CTRL to Select Multiple Staff', 'multiple' => 'true', 'options' => $selected);

echo $form->listBox($model,'team_members', $mem_arr, $htmlOptions);
```

From the above code it works properly. But I have selected variable as an array variable..
then how do i give instead of `'$selected'` array

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could do this (not tested):

```
$result = array(5,6);

$selected = array():
foreach ($result as $selectedIndex) {
    $selected[$selectedIndex] = array('selected'=>'selected');
}
$htmlOptions = array(
    'size' => '5',
    'prompt'=>'Use CTRL to Select Multiple Staff',
    'multiple' => 'true',
    'options' => $selected);

echo $form->listBox($model,'team_members', $mem_arr, $htmlOptions);
```